# how to join multiple JSON array in one JSON using php

Tags: php, json

I manage to get the data I want from database using array_push and encode it into JSON in PHP. The results I get are like below,

```
{
"fName":[
    "ALBERT JUNAIE AK TAWI"
],
"lName":[
    "."
],
"IC":[
    "561203135789"
],
"branch":[
    "Kota Warisan"
],
"phone":[
    "60177741471"
],
"email":[
    "761203135789@kipkad.com.my"
],
"street":[
    "BLOCK E 0106 TAMAN PERMAI RAKYAT LIMA KEDAI GELANG PATAH"
],
"city":[
    "TAMPOI"
],
"postcode":[
    "81000"
],
"state":[
    "JOHOR"
]
}
```

some how i want to group it into something like below, but I don't know how to proceed.Anyone can help me on this? TQ.

```
 {
"account":[
   "fName": "ALBERT JUNAIE AK TAWI",
   "lName": ".",
   "IC": "561203135789",
   "branch":"Kota Warisan",
   "phone":"60177741471",
   "email":"761203135789@kipkad.com.my",
   "street":"BLOCK E 0106 TAMAN PERMAI RAKYAT LIMA KEDAI GELANG PATAH",
   "city":"TAMPOI",
   "postcode":"81000",
   "state":"JOHOR"
]
}
```

Comment: I would start by showing us the code you used to get this data from the database. I think you made the original error in that piece of processing while creating this array. This way we can fix the source of the error and not massage bad results into something usable

Comment: thank you, any how, i get the result i want

Comment: Good for you, oh well, another pool of pie hits the global php code base

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '{"fName":["ALBERT JUNAIE AK TAWI"],"lName":["."],"IC":["561203135789"],"branch":["Kota Warisan"],"phone":["60177741471"],"email":["761203135789@kipkad.com.my"],"street":["BLOCK E 0106 TAMAN PERMAI RAKYAT LIMA KEDAI GELANG PATAH"],"city":["TAMPOI"],"postcode":["81000"],"state":["JOHOR"]}';
```

Or however you are getting your json object $json = ...

```
//first you have to decode the json to a php array
$decoded_json = json_decode($json,true);

// variable to hold our new formatted data
$new_array = array();

// build new array structure
foreach($decoded_json as $key => $val){
    $new_array['account'][$key] = $val[0];
}

// encode the php array back to json 
$encoded_array = json_encode($new_array);

// see the desired result
echo $encoded_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define string input

```
$json = '{"fName":["ALBERT JUNAIE AK TAWI"],"lName":["."],"IC":["561203135789"],"branch":["Kota Warisan"],"phone":["60177741471"],"email":["761203135789@kipkad.com.my"],"street":["BLOCK E 0106 TAMAN PERMAI RAKYAT LIMA KEDAI GELANG PATAH"],"city":["TAMPOI"],"postcode":["81000"],"state":["JOHOR"]}';
```

convert now

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);

$new_array['account'] = array_map(function($k, $v){return [$k =>$v[0]];}, array_keys($array), array_values($array));
echo json_encode($new_array);
```